# Overiding Only Single Core Method In Magento Model

Tags: php, magento

So in my config.xml for a module I am working on I have

```
        <newsletter>
            <rewrite>
                <subscriber>My_Extension_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
            </rewrite>
        </newsletter>
```

and in my module Subscriber.php I have

```
class My_Extension_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model Subscriber
{
    public function subscribe($email)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I just want to double check that I am doing this correctly as I only want to override the subscribe method in the core class and since I am extending the core class I would assume that the core methods would still be accessible. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes.

---

Inheritance means that the `subscribe()` method will be defined in `My_Extension_Model_Subscriber`, and everything else will be inherited from parent classes.

If you want to check your class alias rewrite works, you can either use [Magerun's `dev:class:lookup` command](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#resolvelookup-class-names), or do it manually with an ad-hoc script:

```
# File: /check.php
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber'))); // should output your class
```

Ensure you have cleared your cache first.